# PIXI undefined when import into react component

Tags: reactjs, pixi.js

I have installed pixi : `yarn add pixi.js`

I `import PIXI from pixi.js` and i have no error.
But if i try to log "PIXI" and i got "undefined".

Any clue ?

Thanks

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try: `import * as pixi from 'pixi.js';`

Why is this needed:

`import a from b;` reads the default exported value from b; this means b package should have done `export default value;`

if you want an specific property or method from the package you can also do `import { methodName } from b;`

Answer (score 1):

pixi.js do not have the default exported , pixi.js will register the PIXI into Globel, you only need import from 'pixi.js', then you can use window.PIXI, this is what i used

Comment: Please review your input and fix typos. As of now, I find your answer  very hard to comprehend.